# How can I determine the distance between two portals in Ingress?

Tags: ingress

How can I determine the distance between two portals in Ingress? The intel map doesn't have a scale. Figuring out a linking strategy whilst at home is difficult without a scale.

Answer (score 2):

Completely zoomed in: 100m radius

Fully zoomed out: 0.5 miles radius

Source: first hand experience. Cheat117 is the ingress tag.

Answer (score 1):

Cole Busby's answer is great information for two portals that are less than 0.5 miles away.

But if you want to know the distance between two portals that are further apart, there is this tool: http://smalltowningress.com/portal-distances.html - it works a bit differently though, in that it shows maximum linking distance based on resonator levels, though the distance is also displayed. First you type in the location of a portal, then you can choose different resonator combinations to see the maximum linking distance and if the destination portal is within distance.

I decided to post this because the heart of your question was linking strategy based on portal distances and this tool should help you answer the question, "can I link these two portals, and if not, what is needed?"

Comment: your link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do so without requiring any calculations or use of tools is to go to one of the portals and pull up the key for the other portal.  That key will have a stat on it that tells you how many km it is away.

Answer (score -1):

maps.google.com, right-click on the map where your first portal is (roughly), select "measure distance", right click again where your second portal is, select "distance to here".

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simple [distance calculator](http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-distance-calculator.htm).

Comment: @norfold_s3d How would you get that calculator to calculate the distance between two portals?